# Internet Explorer blocked this site from downloading files

Tags: html, internet-explorer

How to avoid this message in IE:

> "To help protect your security,
>   Internet Explorer blocked this site
>   from downloading files to your
>   computer. Click here for options"

This message occurs while an executable file is downloaded like a link format (http://www.example.com/demo.exe) from Google Mail. It should work without disturbing any changes in IE settings. But while you download the EXE file in new tab it is Working. On direct clicking, it is showing the above mentioned message.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why Do You Write Like This?

Answer (score -1):

Go to tools->internet options->advance, and there you have a series of options you can select or not. Select all that are related to download files, and deselect the ones that restrict them. That should do it.
Another thing you can do is turn of the firewall, but this is not very recommendable.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could be more specific as to which options are going to solve the problem. The Advanced screen can be rather overwhelming.